# text-align: justify not working in some browsers after applying normalize.css

Tags: css, text-align, justify

`text-align: justify` is working fine with this minimal example:

```
<p>Long Loremp Ipsum text.</p>

p { text-align: justify; }
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/nJsuJ/show/light/

If I apply [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/), text alignment is fine in desktop browsers and Opera Mobile, but in Android's default browser and Dolphin it switches to regular left alignment (actually I think it looks worser than left alignment, it's kind of messed up and wobbles around when resizing).

http://fiddle.jshell.net/nJsuJ/1/show/light/

What's going on?

**Works in:**

- Mozilla Firefox 21.0
- Google Chrome 27.0.1453.110
- Opera Mobile 12.10
- Microsoft Internet Explorer 10.0

**Does not work in:**

- Android Browser (not sure which version, it's Android 2.3 Gingerbread)
- Dolphin Browser 9.4.2

Comment: Problem not reproducible in Android 2.3.5. Please provide a more exact description of what actually happens and double-check that it happens for the code in your jsfiddle.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela of course it does happen in the jsfiddle examples. I quadruple-checked it before sending, and `text-rendering: auto;` fixed the issue. Check the screenshots: [original](http://i.imgur.com/3M0iMAt.png), [text-rendering: optimizeLegibility](http://i.imgur.com/R3cFvu6.png) (bugged), [text-rendering: auto](http://i.imgur.com/0Tg0gPD.png) (fixed).

Comment: OK, I did not see that the two URLs in the question that looked the same are actually different and the *second* one demonstrates the problem. It’s an odd bug indeed (and demonstrates that normalize.css may make things rather abnormal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

normalize.css adds in a property, text-rendering: optimizeLegibility. Try turning that off and see how justify works. Justify affects your word spacing, while the text rendering affects your letter spacing. I'd start there.

Comment: Confirmed, that's the problem. So kerning might be broken in those browsers with text-align justify? `text-rendering: auto;` fixed the issue.

Comment: Is there some evidence of Android browsers recognizing `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility` *and* letting it affect alignment? By definition, it has absolutely nothing to do with alignment. And it does *not* affect letter spacing; it may affect ligature behavior and kerning, but these are distinct from letter spacing.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela kerning does affect letter spacing, which in turns affects the alignment (if not properly handled, which must be the case?) All I know is `text-rendering: auto;` fixed it.

Comment: OK, I now see that the solution circumvents the bug. But it’s a genuine bug in the Android browser. By definition, kerning affects only those character pairs for which there is kerning information in the font (if there is such info – I doubt whether Android fonts have it). But there seems to be an odd, and wrong, coupling of properties in the Android browser.

Comment: effects of "text-rendering: optimizeLegibility" can be seen in this nice before/after explanation: http://aestheticallyloyal.com/public/optimize-legibility/